# Bounded sequence and every convergent subsequence converges to L

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a bounded sequence such that every convergent subsequence converges to $L$. Prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = L.$$

The following is my proof. Please let me know what you think.

Prove by contradiction: ($A \wedge  \lnot B$)

Let {$x_n$} be bounded, and every convergent sub-sequence converges to $L$.

Assume that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\ne L$$

Then there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $|x_n - L|\ge \epsilon$ for infinitely many n.

Now, there exists a sub-sequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$ such that $|x_{n_{k}} - L| \ge\epsilon$.

By Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem $x{_{n{_k}}}$ has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_{k{_{l}}}}$ that does not converge to $L$.

$x_{n_{k_{l}}}$ is also a sub-sequence of the original sequence $x_n$, then this is a contradiction since every convergent sub-sequence of $x_n$ converges to $L$.

Hence the assumption is wrong. 
So $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = L.$

Comment: It could be expressed a bit better, but it’s basically fine. Note, though, that it’s not correct to say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ ‘does not go to’ $L$: the limit is a number, and it’s not going anywhere. You simply want to assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\ne L$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Dr. Scott!

Comment: You’re welcome. While I’m here, you might find [this MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful; you posts will be a lot easier to read if you can manage at least basic formatting.

Comment: I fixed it a little bit. Thank you for the website. It's a big help. I haven't figure out how to write xnk or xnkl yet though.

Comment: Subscripts nested three deep are a pain, and hard to read, but you can do them: `x_{n_{k_\ell}}`, for $x_{n_{k_\ell}}$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @wj32, it's a bit different from that earlier question, which talks of metric spaces and compact sets --- topics which someone interested in the current question may not know about.

Comment: Just a wording suggestion: writing $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\neq L$ implies that a limit esists. A more rigorous wording could be "$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ does not exist or it is different from $L$". In either case, your proof works.

Comment: The Q as stated is trivial because a sequence is a subsequence of itself, and for any $m$ the sequence $(x_n)_{n>m}$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)_{n\in N}.$ It would be non-trivial to ask whether ($x_n)_{n\in N}$ converges to $L$ if $(x_{f(n)})_{n\in N}$ converges to $L$ whenever $f:N\to N$ is strictly increasing and  $N$ \ $\{f(n):n\in N\}$ is infinite.

Comment: Since you need Bolzano-Weierstrass, you should make the ambient space more explicit than what the notation $|x_{n_{k}} - L| \ge\epsilon$ suggests: it is restricted to $\Bbb R,$ or at least $\Bbb R^n.$

Answer (score 2):

I revise your proof.

Let {$x_n$} be bounded, and every subsequence converges to L.
Assume that $lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n)\ne L$.
Then there exists an epsilon such that infinitely many $n \in N \implies  |x_n - L|\ge \epsilon $
Now, there exists a subsequence $\{ x_{\Large{n_k}} \}$ such that $|x_{\Large{n_k}} - L|\ge \epsilon \quad \color{red}{(♫)}$

> **1.** How to presage proof by contradiction? Why not a direct proof?
>
> **2.** Where does $\color{red}{(♫)}$ issue from?

By Bolzano Weiertrass Theorem $\{ x_{\Large{n_k}} \}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{ x_{n_{k_l}} \}$ that doesn't converge to L. This is a contradiction.

Why? $\{ x_{\Large{n_{k_l}}} \}$ is a sub sequence of the sub sequence $x_{\Large{n_k}} $, which was posited to converge to L.
By the agency of [p 57 q2.5.1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/776880/85079), every convergent sub sequence of $x_n$ converges to the same limit as the original sequence. So $\{ x_{\Large{n_{k_l}}} \} \to L$.