# Convergent subsequences converge to the same limit as the original sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I was studying the following problem which is nicely solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776899/if-every-convergent-subsequence-converges-to-a-then-so-does-the-original-boun). The problem is as follows:

> Assume $(a_{n})$ is a bounded sequence such that every convergent subsequence of $(a_{n})$ converges to the same limit $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Show $(a_{n})$ must converge to $a$.

Now I am trying to see the necessity of $a_n$ to be bounded. Can you give me any counter-example when the above statement does not hold for a sequence that is not bounded?

Comment: If $a_n=n$, the hypothesis is vacuously satisfied.

Comment: What is the convergent subsequence of $a_n=n$? Do you think it is a valid counter-example? If there is no converging subsequence --> every convergent subsequence converges to the same limit?

Comment: A counterexample in the nonbounded case is given by $a_n = (1+(-1)^n)n$ (and this sequence *has* convergent subsequences)

Comment: Now it makes things clear. Thanks @TheSilverDoe !

Comment: @DavidMitra What do you mean ? All the convergent subsequences of $(a_n)$ converge to the same limit (which is $0$) in my example.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Oh, sorry...