# Do we need to have a subsequence such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left\|x_{n_k}\right\|=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\|x_n\right\|$?

Tags: analysis, limits, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(X,\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|)$ be a normed space and $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq X$. Can we prove that there is a subsequence $\left(x_{n_k}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left\|x_{n_k}\right\|=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\|x_n\right\|\;?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and this holds more generally for real sequences. In fact, the limit inferior of a sequence can be defined as the least limit point of any subsequence of the sequence.

To prove that such a subsequence exists, recall that,
$$\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \inf\limits_{k \ge n} a_k$$
Let the limit inferior be $L$ and fix an integer $m  > 0$. By the above limit being $L$, we may choose some $n$ such that
$$\left| \inf\limits_{k \ge n} a_k - L\right| < \frac{1}{2m}.$$
By definition of an infimum, we may choose some $n_m \ge n$ such that,
$$\left| \inf\limits_{k \ge n} a_k - a_{n_m}\right| < \frac{1}{2m}.$$
Using the triangle inequality,
$$\left| a_{n_m} - L\right| \le \left| \inf\limits_{k \ge n} a_k - L\right| + \left| \inf\limits_{k \ge n} a_k - a_{n_m}\right| < \frac{1}{m}.$$
By squeeze theorem, $a_{n_m} \rightarrow L$.

Comment: Maybe you should note that we need $L>-\infty$.

Comment: What can we do if $L=-\infty$?

Comment: It depends on how you define $\lim\inf a_n = -\infty$. What definition do you use?

Comment: I define $\liminf a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf_{k\ge n}a_k$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=-\infty$ means that for all $r\in\mathbb R$ there is a $N\in\mathbb N$ with $b_n\le r$ for all $n\ge N$.

Comment: That's the limit definition to $-\infty$. What about the definition of the limit-inferior being $-\infty$? Would you just keep it the same as the finite case, but allow $\inf_{k \ge n} a_k$ to be $-\infty$ when $\{a_k : k \ge n\}$ is not bounded below?

Comment: As I wrote, $\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n$ is defined in terms of the limit of the sequence $(\inf_{k\ge n}a_k)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. So the definition of the limit being $-\infty$ applies. I treat all sequences as being subsets of the extended real numbers $[-\infty,\infty]$. Maybe that's where the confusion comes from.

Comment: OK, in that case, we know that $\inf_{k \ge n} a_k = -\infty$ by definition if $\{a_k : k \ge n\}$ is unbounded (finitely) from below, or contains $-\infty$. If $-\infty$ occurs infinitely often in the sequence, then we have our convergent subsequence to $-\infty$. If not, then let $x_{n_1}$ be the first term after the last occurrence of $-\infty$. Since $\{a_k : k \ge n_1 + 1\}$ is unbounded below, choose $n_2 > n_1$ such that $a_{n_2} < -2$. Since $\{a_k : k \ge n_2 + 1\}$ is bounded below, find $n_3 > n_2$ such that $a_{n_3} < -3$, etc. Find $a_{n_k}$ such that $a_{n_k} < -k$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Your question can be greatly reduced. The normed space and its norm can be "forgotten" because both the limit and the $\liminf$ are applied to sequences of real numbers ($||x_n||$ is a real number!), and the question simply becomes:

> For a given sequence of positive real numbers $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$, does there exist a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ such that $$\lim_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k}= \liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n$$

This question is much simpler to answer and is almost trivial, depending on your definition of $\limsup$.

Comment: Right, in fact I favor the definition of $\liminf $ as the minimum subsequential limit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: this is the same as proving that for a real sequence $(a_n)_k$ there is a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ such that
$$ \lim_{k} a_{n_k} = \liminf_n a_n = l, $$
say.

To do this, we basically imitate one of the proofs of Bolzano–Weierstrass (the "high points" one) (or see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581128/prove-that-subsequence-converges-to-limsup)): pick a sequence $\varepsilon_k \to 0$. Then for each $\varepsilon_k$, there are, by the definition of the limit inferior, an infinite number of $n$ such that $ \lvert a_{n} - l \rvert < \varepsilon_k $. Choose $n_k$ as the smallest of these $n$ not already chosen, and then you find that $(a_{n_k})_k$ satisfies $ 0 \leqslant \lvert a_{n_k} - l \rvert < \varepsilon_k \to 0$, so $a_{n_k} \to l $.

Comment: Does the same approach work if $l=-\infty$?