# Let (a_n) be a sequence of real numbers which is bounded above and $a_n\not\rightarrow -\infty$ then $a_n$ has a convergent subsequence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers which is bounded above and $a_n\not\rightarrow -\infty$ then $a_n$ has a convergent subsequence.

I think I will be done if I can show that there is a $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for each $n_0$ there is an $n>n_0$ such that $a_n\ge M$. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with the definition of $\limsup$, this answers your question.
By hypothesis $\exists M\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $a_n\leq M,\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Set $b_m$:=$sup_{k\geq m}a_k$.
$\{b_m\}_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a decreasing sequence and ${b_m}\leq M$. Moreover $b_m$ is a convergent sequence and $L:=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}b_m=\limsup_{m\rightarrow\infty}a_m>-\infty$, otherwise by the sandwich theorem you would have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=-\infty$. Now you are done since it is known ([otherwise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581128/prove-that-subsequence-converges-to-limsup))  that there exists a subsequence converging to the $\limsup$.
In general, you cannot bound $a_n$ from below since you can have something like $$a_n=
\left\{ \begin{array}
        - -n\ \ \  if\ n \ is\  not\  a\  multiple\  of\  10\\
        1\ \ \ \ \  if\  n\  is\  a\  multiple\  of\  10
        \end{array}\right.$$