# Checking limit of function by subsequence

Tags: analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function which has the following property:

(1)$\quad$  Every sequence $x_n\rightarrow x$ has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $f(x_{n_k})\rightarrow f(x)$.

Prove that

$$
(2)\quad \lim_{y\rightarrow x}f(y)=f(x)
$$

**Proof by contradiction.** Suppose that (2) does not hold. Then, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and a sequence $x_n\rightarrow x$ such that $|f(x_n)-f(x)|\geq \varepsilon$. This contradicts to the assumption (1).

**My questions.**

1) Could we give a direct proof for the above fact without using proof by contradiction?

2) Can we give a visual explanation (intuition) for the above fact?

Thank you for all the answers.

Comment: Think about the counterpositive, that is: If the limit $\lim_{y\rightarrow x}f(y)$ does not go to $f(x)$, you can define some sequence $(x_{n})$ such that $x_{n}$ converges to $x$ but $f(x_{n})$ does not converges to $f(x).$ Can you see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well sure we could give a direct proof, take $\{x_n\},\{y_n\}$ sequences converging to $x$, such that $$f(x_n)\to \lim_{r\searrow0}\sup_{z\in(x-r,x+r)}f(z),$$
$$f(y_n)\to\lim_{r\searrow 0}\inf_{z\in(x-r,x+r)}f(z).$$
Then choose $\{{x_{n}}_k\},\{{y_n}_k\}$ subsequence with $$f({x_{n}}_k),f({y_n}_k)\to f(x).$$
Then since subsequences of convergent sequences converge to the same limit
$$\lim_{r\searrow 0}\inf_{z\in(x-r,x+r)}f(z)=f(x)=\lim_{r\searrow0}\sup_{z\in(x-r,x+r)}f(z),$$
hence $\lim_{z\to x}f(z)$ exists and equals $f(x).$

Comment: Why can we choose ${x_{n_k}}$ and ${y_{n_k}}$?

Comment: We're assuming if $z_n\to x$ for any sequence $\{z_n\},$ then we can choose a subsequence ${z_n}_k$ such that $f({z_n}_k)\to f(x).$

Comment: Please explain why we can choose $x_n, y_n$?

Comment: @egorovik Take $$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$ to be $1$ on all irrationals, and $0$ on all rationals. Then $\lim_r\sup_{z\in(x-r,x+r)}f(z)=1\not=0=f(0).$ We cannot assume the limit inferior and limit superior are just $f(x),$ as that condition is equivalent to the limit existing, and being $f(x).$ That's circular logic.

Comment: Please explain clearer...

Comment: In my point of view, you use limsup and liminf to solve my problem?

Comment: @Blind It is a general property that you always have sequence converging to the liminf/limsup, and $\lim_{z\to x}f(z)=f(x)$ is equivalent to $$\lim_{r\to x}\sup_{z\in(x-r,x+r)} f(z)=\lim_{r\to x}\inf_{z\in(x-r,x+r)}f(z)=f(x).$$

Comment: @Blind Here is a proof for the sequence limit case, we are dealing with a continuous limit here, but the proof there isn't too hard to modify for the continuous limit case. 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581128/prove-that-subsequence-converges-to-limsup

Here's one about the equivalence of the limits 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122755/sequence-converges-iff-limsup-liminf

I don't have space here for a detailed reply, but hopefully the links help.