# "Counterexample" to this characterization of lim sup?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, limsup-and-liminf

I came across an exercise (Exercise 10, Ch. 1, Marsden's elementary classical analysis, 2nd ed.) that gives a characterization of lim sup I had never seen, which can be rephrased as follows:

> Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Then there is some $l \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\limsup x_{n} = l$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $N \geq 1$ such that $x_{n} < l+\varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$ and $x_{n} > l-\varepsilon$ for some $n \geq N$.

The "only if" part is obvious, but I am afraid (not sure) the "if" part is false. For, let $(x_{n})$ be the sequence such that $x_{1} := 1$ and $x_{n} := 0$ for all $n \geq 2$. Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $x_{n} < 1+\varepsilon$ for all $n \geq 1$ and, since $x_{1} = 1$, we have $x_{n} > 1 - \varepsilon$ for some $n \geq 1$. But $\limsup x_{n} = 0 \neq 1$. Is my counterexample wrong or is the exercise wrong?

Comment: The last part of the book's characterization of lim sup should say that "for all $N \ge 1$, $x_n > l-\epsilon$ for some $n \ge N$." Are you sure you rephrased the book's definition correctly?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I re-checked the book. The exercise is the Exercise 10 for Chapter 1 in Marsden's analysis, second edition. And, yes, I rephrased it correctly.

Comment: Yes, it may be one of the book's typo...

Comment: The characterization mentioned in JimmyK4542's comment is also mentioned in this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778876/characterization-of-lim-sup-lim-inf

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the book has [a website](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/books/Elementary_Classical_Analys.html) where some pdf-files with errata are published.

Comment: Thank you; was not aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer to allow the question to be marked as answered:

I checked the book; the rephrasing is correct; as stated in the comments, it's a mistake in the book.