# limit supreme and infimo

Tags: real-analysis

Plase explain with an example the form correct of:
$ \displaystyle {\limsup_{n\to \infty} s_n = s^* }$ with Rudin definition, because $s^* =\sup E $ and $ E $ is all point of subsequential limits. 
Because iam confused.

Comment: This question has been discussed at length here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281807/two-definitions-of-limsup

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence 
$$ s_n=(-1)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right). $$
Then the set of subsequential limit points is $E=\{-1,1\}$, and we have
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty}s_n=\sup E=1. $$

For a slightly more complicated example, look at the sequence which is something like
$$ \{s_n\}=(1,1,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},1,\ldots) $$
Then the set of subsequential limit points is
$$ E=\left\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}, $$
and 
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty}s_n=\sup E=1. $$

Comment: Well more accurately $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{(n!)^{1/n}}=\sup E$, and $E=\{0\}$, but yes its correct.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can cocontinue